# Specifications of infrared LED VX-301

Tags: infrared

During clean up I found an old pack of IR LEDs.

They were bought ~ 20 years ago from the German electronics retailer conrad.de. The order number is 185540, but unfortunately, the store doesn't know that component, anymore.

The part is named VX-301.

I couldn't find any datasheet for it online.
Thus, I'm curious of their specification, especially:

- wavelength
- viewing angle
- intensity
- current ratings

Does anyone know some details about this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something. On this page https://www.flippermarkt.de/community/forum/threads/leds-fuer-optos-und-brueckengleichrichter-woher.56836/

There is a discussion in german regarding two alternatives of diodes and a receiver:

Was ich schon probiert hab und was funktioniert sind folgende von CONRAD:

Sender / IR EMITTER
IR-EMITTER LD274/Q62703-Q1031, Artikel-Nr.: 153641 – 62 , >50mW, 950nm, 0,58 EUR
Oder:

## VX-301 IR-SENDEDIODE, Artikel-Nr.: 185540 – 62, 80mW, 895nm, 1,28 €

Empfänger
FOTO TRANSISTOR BPW 40 = BPW 96 C, Artikel-Nr.: 184055 – 62 0,91 EUR
BPW96: 620 – 980 nm; BPW40: 520 – 950 nm

So the diode might be 80 mW 895nm

Comment: fwiw, http://sites.prenninger.com/elektronik/aatis-praxisheft/praxisheft/praxisheft-13 also talks about the VX-301 having 80 mW/sr.